# Create delegates for a NSOperation : callback problem

Tags: objective-c, delegates, nsoperation

I'm facing a problem in a simple TableView : i want to refresh the data from the Net in a separate thread to avoid blocking the UI. I've created a NSoperation that will do the job. This object creates an other object to handle the download. The delegate of the downloader is the NSoperation Object.

My problem is that my NSoperation Object does not get any call back from the Downloader.

If I don't you a separate thread, using the same code (and calling main method), it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code would be nice. Is there any chance you use NSURLRequest in that separate thread? If so, try spawning the NSURLRequest on the main thread (NSURLRequest can be async by itself anyway, so that is perfectly fine).

*EDIT* I meant NSURLConnection, not request.

Comment: What will be the right design then ? Do I create the NSURLConnection and then create an NSoperation passing this connection as an argument of the init for instance OR bring back the downloader into the ViewController (and only create an NSoperation for the parsing ?

Comment: As I've said before; example code would be nice to have an insight of what you are actually doing at this moment. My advice; Spawn that NSOperation in a new thread. Create a function in that object that you call on the main-thread. In that function, you set up your async NSURLConnection and set the NSOperation as delegate (so the callbacks will be to the NSOperation).

Comment: Or, if you are really stuck, take a look at ASIHTTPRequest (which is an NSOperation by itself and has full support for NSOperationQueues and async stuff).

Comment: Ok. I've got it. I'm going to refactor this and keep you informed.

Comment: It works perfectly ! I took the code of my downloader init method that create the connection and made a method of this code (in the same downloader object) Then, in the Init method, I replaced the missing code by a [self performOnMainThread] with that new method. I wish I could reward you ten times :)-

Answer (score 1):

As Mirage said, the NSURLConnection is designed to use a runloop. You get a running runloop setup for you on the main thread, but in other threads you create the runloop has to be managed manually (basically you have to run it).

My advice would be to use a concurrent NSOperation and in the start method check if you are on the main thread: if not, call again the start method on the main thread and bail out

```
-(void)start 
{
     if ([NSThread mainThread] != [NSThread currentThread]) {
           [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(start)];
           return;
     }
     rest of the real code is here ....
}
```

The other options (cleaner but definitely harder) is to create an NSOperation that manages an internal runloop (or one supplied by the caller), so that async APIs that need it (like NSURLConnection) can be run on threads different than main.

Search for "LinkedImageFetcher" sample in the official api: the class QRunLoopOperation does exactly that.